# select from every two rows in MySQL, using different columns for matching

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

I have a MySQL table which has the following structure:

> ```
>  mysql> select id,channel,Stats,Bridged from channels;
>  +----------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
>  | id       | channel                         | Stats   | Bridged                       |
>  +----------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
>  | 21523318 | SIP/5602291658-0007f140         | Up      | SIP/X.Y.Z.Q-0007f13f          >      |
>  | 21523321 | SIP/X.Y.Z.Q-0007f13f            | Up      | SIP/5602291658-0007f140       |
>  | 21523322 | SIP/5154642553-0007f13a         | Up      | SIP/402-0007f135              |
>  | 21523323 | SIP/402-0007f135                | Up      | SIP/5154642553-0007f13a       |
> ```

Look at each two records, they are paired: for example ID 21523318  has Channel identical with Bridged column from next ID.

My question is: taking into account that the table usually holds several thousands entries, how could I select a single line for each two records?

I mean -- once I have the first line and I can verify that the "Bridged" column info exists as "channel" in the db, to display a single line. I can do this recursively (checking for each line if there's another Bridged channel , but for several thousands it becomes very slow and there are a lot of queries.
I was thinking of doing inner join with the same table on channel=Bridged and then somehow do a group by or something...

Any clues or ideas on how I should proceed?

Comment: select a.*,b.* FROM channels a JOIN channels b ON b.bridged = a.channel;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If channel and bridged are always swapped, this should work for you:

```
select *
from channels
where id in (
  select min(id)
  from channels
  group by least(channel, bridged), greatest(channel, bridged))
```

Answer (score 0):

Join it to itself:

> select * from channels c0
>   join channels c1 on c0.channel = c1.Bridged

Comment: still gives me info on separate rows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a self inner join should do.

Further, you could add an index on channel, bridged.

```
select C1.id, C2.id, C1.Stats, C2.Stats, C1.channel 
from channels C1 inner join channels C2 
on C1.channel = C2.Bridged;
```

Comment: still gives me info on separate rows :)

Comment: Are you sure? If that is the case, I think I am missing something. Can you show the desired output based on the sample-set that you have in this question?

Comment: 21523318 | 21523221  | Up      |  Up<br> 21523221 | 21523318  | Up      |  Up<br> The above is the output from your query

Comment: Output should be on a single line, not two lines (because that's how i got them initially anyway. Joining them only verifies that the 'channel' column is identical to 'bridged', but doesn't put them on the same row

Answer (score 0):

I ~think~ this will be a little faster...

```
select a.*
     , b.* 
  FROM channels a 
  JOIN channels b 
    ON b.bridged = a.channel
   AND b.channel = a.bridged
   AND b.id > a.id;
```

Comment: why faster, min / least would probably have the same speed as the ">" operator ?

Comment: @Strawberry this is a nice solution :) but I think it's better to use a LEFT JOIN, with `b.id < a.id` and `WHERE b.id IS NULL` because if a record doesn't match with any other, it has to be shown

Comment: @fthiella Does it? I don't see that in the specification. Either way, this is how I'd do it, and at present the data set's too small for performance to be an issue.